# Django - What is the best way to filter out softly deleted rows?

Tags: django, database-design

When my program performs a *soft deletion*, the softly deleted rows would be marked as inactive or deleted (e.g. `person.deleted=True`). The question is, what is the best way to make sure that every retrieval of data from this table would only return the *active* records without having to add the `deleted=False` argument to the `filter` method (which is not only repetitive, but also prone to errors).

Comment: Selecting data from a `VIEW` instead of a `TABLE` is one way to achieve this. Not sure if there's any other way.  You can't, however, modify data on a `VIEW`, as it's content is but a product of a SQL query, so your code will have to include `SELECT` queries that fetch data from the `VIEW` and `UPDATE/INSERT` queries that modify data in the original `TABLE`, which can be somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating custom object manager for your model. This may be enough or not, depending on your requirements and further project implementation.

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = PersonManager()

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PersonManager, self).filter(deleted=False)

    def deleted(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PersonManager, self).filter(deleted=True)
    # ...
```

**Update:** Another convenient way to do that is with [django-livefield](https://github.com/hearsaycorp/django-livefield)